# how to replace a old dll with the newer version of that .dll in tfs repository

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I need to replace a old `.dll` with the newer version of the `.dll` in the TFS repository.

Can anyone tell me the procedure how to do that? 
I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @varun - what exactly are you trying to accomplish.  I think you need to take a step back and explain the higher level thing you want to achieve.

Comment: why do you have DLLs in version control?  Are these third party DLLs?  You might want to consider making a sep 'tree' for each different 'version set' of third party libs

Comment: Hi all, their is a old .lib in tfs which i need to replace with a newer version of lib. But for this i need .dll, to replace these .dll in debug as well as release folder and compile the source code.This lib is a third party.

Comment: I tried many times but i am getting a lot of linker errors and in existing projects some errors are cannot open include file .dll. can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to check in the .dll files into TFS. You can upload the references to a package manager such as NuGet. Then you can specify the version you want to use in your project, and your project will restore the packages automatically.

Useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/publish-a-package
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is more or less the same as for any other file:

1. Check-out the file in question using the Source Control Explorer
2. Replace the old file with the new using your favorite file explorer (had it been a source file you would just have done edits to the existing file using the IDE).
3. Check-in the file using the Source Control Explorer

I agree with @cece that in general you should avoid storing binary files in source control.

Comment: Why "you should avoid storing binary files in source control"?

Comment: @usefulBee you should not store binary files in a source control system because source control systems are developed for source and optimizes that by storing differences between two versions. Adding binary files will prevent just storing the changes and you will not be able to see the difference. For binaries you could use a package management system.